# Get link from Linker Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have an  tag that when the user clicks it redirects to a custom link created using Jquery.

I have something like this:

```
<a id="test"></a>

<script>
    $("#test").click(function()
    {
        var link  = "test.org/test.php?variable_1=something&variable_2=something";

        window.open(link);
    });
</script>
```

My problem is that I also need to append to that link the _ga variable from Google Analytics Linker but I don't know how can I get the code generated by it.
I need yo have something like this:

```
<a id="test"></a>

<script>
    $("#test").click(function()
    {

        //Gets ga code to append to link
        var ga_code = ...


        var link  = "test.org/test.php?_ga="+ga_code+"&variable_1=something&variable_2=something";

        window.open(link);
    });
</script>
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: maybe helpful https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/

Comment: I already looked at that page but I can't find what I want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the next function to get the linker parameter:

```
function getCrossdomainLinker(){
    if (typeof(window["ga"]) !== "undefined") {
        var firstTracker = ga.getAll()[0];
        if (firstTracker) { return firstTracker.get("linkerParam"); }
    }
}
```

It will return sosmething like:

```
"_ga=2.248329664.639135579.1523283935-2097469629.1523283935"
```

An you'll have to add it to your link:

```
<script>

    function getCrossdomainLinker() {
        if (typeof(window["ga"]) !== "undefined") {
            var firstTracker = ga.getAll()[0];
            if (firstTracker) { return firstTracker.get("linkerParam"); }
        }
    }

    $("#test").click(function() {

        //Gets ga code to append to link
        var ga_code = getCrossdomainLinker();

        var link  = "test.org/test.php?"+ga_code+"&variable_1=something&variable_2=something";

        window.open(link);
    });
</script>
```

More Info: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/linker